# PostgreSQL - what does symbol ||| do?

Tags: string, postgresql, concatenation, operator-keyword

I found such code:

```
SELECT 'a' ||| 'b';
```

I tried to google the meaning of this operator, but google ignores symbolic data. SymbolHound did not return any meaningful results.

I tested it one PostgreSQL 8.4 server and 9.1 server.

In PostgreSQL 8.4, it is same as string concatenation, with one difference:

```
SELECT 'a' ||| 'b'; -- 'ab'
SELECT 'a' || 'b'; -- 'ab'

SELECT 'a' ||| NULL; -- 'a'
SELECT 'a' || NULL; -- NULL
```

In PostgreSQL 9.1, this operator is not defined.

```
SELECT 'a' ||| 'b'; -- ERROR
SELECT 'a' || 'b'; -- 'ab'
SELECT 'a' || NULL; -- NULL
```

Is this officially documented somewhere? Is this configuration-specific?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`|||` isn't a standard operator shipped with PostgreSQL; [as you can see here, it doesn't exist in stock 8.4 either](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/d41d8/20). I'd say someone installed it with [`CREATE OPERATOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) in your 8.4 install.

Try using the `psql` command `\do` (ie "describe operators") in the 8.4 DB, or do a `pg_dump` and examine the dump for the definition of the operator and its associated function.

`select * from pg_operator where oprname = '|||';` may also be useful. Note the `oprcode` column, which shows the function that implements the operator.

Comment: The special NULL behavior of `|||` is rather suggestive.

Comment: You are 100% correct, select * from pg_operator where oprname = '|||'; returned operator, that is defined by function "textcat_null".